# How to enhance Wordpress WYSIWYG user experience?

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor, wysiwyg, user-experience

I've been using Wordpress for several project and I figured out the WYSIWYG editor is always far away from what you actualy get.
Some customers told me it couldn't even be called a WYSIWYG because the CSS was not the same in the editor and in the final webpage.

Is there any plugin / trick to enhance this issue?

Thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add the Theme stylesheet as `content_css` property for the Visual Editor using the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'visual_css_so_8007234' );

function visual_css_so_8007234() {
    return get_stylesheet_uri();
}
```